# Make windows form application block console

Tags: visual-studio-2012

As I am completly inexperienced in using visual studio I ask the question here.

I have an Windows Form application thats needs to run from console and block until it is closed. The idea is to call it from C code with system() and the C code should block until the Windows Form application is blocked.

How can I setup in visual studio that the created exe does not detach from console after launch?

Answer (score 1):

The system() function uses the command processor to start the program.  Which only blocks until the program terminates when the program you asked it to start is a console mode app.  Yours is not, a GUI app is expected to create its own window so there's no reason to wait.  Alter your command to force it to wait, like this:

```
 system("start /wait c:\\windows\\notepad.exe");
```